# Optimize zgrep using awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a list of files (/c/Users/Roy/DataReceived) over which I want to grep some information and store it as txt files(/c/Users/Roy/Documents/Result).

For example purposes: Imagine I have a 20 files with different information about cities, and I want to grep information for the cities that are listed in a txt file. All this information will then be stored in another txt file that would have the name of the given city (NewYork.txt, Rome.txt, etc).

The following code is working:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare INPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/DataReceived
declare OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/Documents/Result

while read -r city; do
  echo $city
  zgrep -Hwi "$city" "${INPUT_DIRECTORY}/"*.vcf.gz > "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${city}.txt"
done < list_of_cities.txt
```

However, this process takes around a week to run fully.
My question is, is there a way to unzip the files just once? Using awk for example? This would make the process twice as fast.

Also, is there any other way of optimizing the process?

Comment: Depending on the shape of the data, you might want to run `zgrep` just once, and then pick apart the output with Awk. A better approach is perhaps to unzip everything once to standard output, then run Awk on the result; `zcat files | awk 'NR==FNR { city[$1]++; next } ... }' list_of_cities.txt -`

Comment: and why making any passes, why not using a regex in grep?

Comment: The way you're grep-ing will probably result in false matches (e.g. you want a city named `Foo` but match on a country or state/province named `Foo`). Show us some sample input (a few lines resulting from `zcat`-ing your zipped file **that'd be useful for testing purposes**) and expected output so we can help you. Also, do you really need a separate file of city names so you can exclude some cities or do you actually just want a separate output file for every city in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should be several times faster than your solution:

```bash
zgrep -Hwif list_of_cities.txt /c/Users/Roy/DataReceived/*.vcf.gz |
awk -F ':' '
    NR == FNR {
        regex = regex sep "(" $0 ")"
        sep = "|"
        next
    }
    match($NF,regex) {
        city = tolower(substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH))
        print > ( "/c/Users/Roy/Documents/Result/" city ".txt")
    }
' list_of_cities.txt -
```

But if your `list_of_cities.txt` only contains **literal** city names (and not **regexps**) then it'll be faster to do something like this:

```bash
zgrep -HwiFf list_of_cities.txt /c/Users/Roy/DataReceived/*.vcf.gz |
awk -F ':' '
    NR == FNR {
        cities[$0]
        next
    }
    {
        split($NF,words,'[^[:alnum:]_]+')
        for (c in cities)
            if (c in words) {
                city = tolower(c)
                break
            }
        print > ( "/c/Users/Roy/Documents/Result/" city ".txt")
    }
' list_of_cities.txt -
```

**Limitation:** If the matched lines or file paths can contain a `:` character then the current `awk` codes will break.

Comment: Thanks @Fravadona, but is that correct? Shouldn't be  `zgrep -Hwif "$city" "${INPUT_DIRECTORY}/"*.vcf.gz | awk -F ':' '{print > ( "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/ tolower($city)" .txt")}'`

Comment: @RoyBatty you're reading `$city` from `list_of_cities.txt` no? `zgrep -f list_of_cities.txt` will search for all the regexps in `list_of_cities.txt` at once so it's a lot faster. But I just realised a problem with the `awk`; let me try to correct it. Are the cities names string literals or regexps?

Comment: Thanks @Fravadona, there are still some things I don't understand. Why print $NF? I would like the whole row. Also, hos is this awk command preventing of unzipping the file many times?

Comment: @RoyBatty with `zgrep -H` the output will be of the form `filepath:matched line`; I use `$NF` for getting `matched line` and extract the city name from it (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you really need is something like the following, assuming the zipped file contains CSV with the city in the 3rd field:

```
zcat "${INPUT_DIRECTORY}/"*.vcf.gz |
sort -t',' -k3,3 |
awk -F',' -v outDir="$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" '
    $3 != prev {
        close(out)
        out = outDir "/" $3 ".txt"
    }
    { print > out }
'
```

If the file isn't CSV then change each `','` separator to whatever separator it really is, and if the city isn't in the 3rd field then change each `3` to whatever field number it really is.

If you really do need to reduce the output to a specific list of cities then:

```
zcat "${INPUT_DIRECTORY}/"*.vcf.gz |
sort -t',' -k3,3 |
awk -F',' -v outDir="$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" '
    NR == FNR {
        cities[$0]
        next
    }
    !($3 in cities) {
        next
    }
    $3 != prev {
        close(out)
        out = outDir "/" $3 ".txt"
    }
    { print > out }
' list_of_cities.txt -
```

Comment: `zgrep -H` prepends the filepath to each line of result, so I guess OP wants to keep this info in the results; I might be wrong though

Comment: @Fravadona Yeah, I noticed that but figured whatever they need it'll be an easy tweak once they provide sample input/output. Its also possible that if they do need a specific list of cities then doing a zgrep for those instead of zcat could speed things up by reducing the initial input to awk.